# .NET Core middleware invalidoperationexception

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, hangfire, asp.net-core-middleware

I am using hangfire authentication for .NET Core and when I am authenticating the .NET Core kestrel will complain that StatusCode cannot be set because the response has already started. Have anyone encountered something similar error?

Error:

```
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContext.ThrowResponseAlreadyStartedException(String name)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContext.set_StatusCode(Int32 value)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContext.Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.IHttpResponseFeature.set_StatusCode(Int32 value)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.DefaultHttpResponse.set_StatusCode(Int32 value)
at Hangfire.Dashboard.AspNetCoreDashboardMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.MapMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContextOfT`1.ProcessRequestAsync()
```

My best guess was because of the Challenge method setting the statuscode. Is this the wrong way to set the statusCode?

```
public bool Authorize(DashboardContext dashboardContext)
    {
        HttpContext context = dashboardContext.GetHttpContext();

        string header = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"];

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(header))
        {
            AuthenticationHeaderValue authValues = AuthenticationHeaderValue.Parse(header);

            if ("Basic".Equals(authValues.Scheme, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                string parameter = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(authValues.Parameter));
                string[] parts = parameter.Split(':');

                if (parts.Length > 1)
                {
                    string username = parts[0];
                    string password = parts[1];

                    if ((!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(username)) && (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password)))
                    {
                        return Users.Any(user => user.ValidateUser(username, password)) || Challenge(context);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // ** The error appear when it return false
        return Challenge(context);
    }

    private static bool Challenge(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
        context.Response.Headers.Append("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=\"Hangfire Dashboard\"");

        context.Response.WriteAsync("Authentication is required.");

        return false;
    }
```

This is how I am using the middleware at the startup

```
public virtual void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IRecurringJobManager recurringJobManager)
{
   ...
   DashboardOptions options = new DashboardOptions
   {
        DashboardTitle = "Hangfire Scheduler",
        Authorization = new[] {
            new CustomAuthorizationFilter(new[]
            {
                // TODO: change to appsettings
                new HangfireUserCredentials
                {
                    Username = _configuration["Scheduler:username"],
                    Password = _configuration["Scheduler:password"]
                }
            })
        }
     };
     app.UseHangfireDashboard("/scheduler", options);
  ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, StatusCode must be set before any output to the response as stated by the error message, Headers probably as well.

Comment: @schnitz77 hmm, where should I set the statuscode?

Comment: Doesn't seem the right location is in the code you posted but it must be set before any output to the response.

Comment: @schnitz77 based on what I had trace, when pointing to the hangfire dashboard it will have a 200 response, but it does not have an authentication so at (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(header)) it will check if authentication parameter exist in the httprequestheader and if it does not exist it will set the response to 401 and etc.

Comment: I see. Status 200 is the default value. If you encounter an error setting StatusCode, something you don't show here already modified the response, i'm sorry.

Comment: @schnitz77 thanks for the clue that status 200 is the default value. I manage to fix it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the bug where I have to pass the httpcontext over from the startup or else the httpcontext is a default httpcontext.

```
 DashboardOptions options = new DashboardOptions
 {
       DashboardTitle = "Markono Scheduler",
       IsReadOnlyFunc = (DashboardContext context) => !customAuthorizationFilter.Authorize(context),
 };
```